# How to use the regular expression to make the Pig Latin game?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to get a single match for the first consonant or consonant cluster in an input. Then the program should move the consonant to the beginning of the word and add "ay" at the end.

Here is my code

```
import re
consonants = [ 'bl', 'cl', 'fl', 'gl', 'pl', 'sl', 'br', 'cr', 'dr', 'fr', 'gr','pr', 'tr', 'sc', 'sk', 'sm', 'sn', 'sp', 'st', 'sw', 'tw','b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
word1 = str(input("Type something"))
word2 = re.split(r'[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]' or '[bl]''[cl]''[fl]', word1)

if any(consonants in word2 for consonants in consonants):
    print(word2[1] + word2[0] + word2[2] + "ay")
```

The output does not appear in the interactive console.

Comment: The expression `r'[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]' or '[bl]''[cl]''[fl]'` is surely not doing what you want, though I'm not actually sure what that is.

Comment: it is obvious I am new to programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved the program.

```
        import re 

words1 = input("Input Sentence:") 

b1 = re.search(r"([^aeoiu]*)([aeoiu]*)([^aeoiu]*)([aeoiu]*)([^aeoiu]*)", words1) 

b2 = b1.group(1) 
b3 = b1.group(2) 
b4 = b1.group(3) 
b5 = b1.group(4) 
b6 = b1.group(5) 

if b5 != 5: 

    print(b3 +  b4 + b5 + b6 + b2 +  "ay")
```

Answer (score 1):

Right, Python does not do "magic"; `or` is a well-defined operator which takes two boolean expressions and produces a boolean expression, not something which magically combines two regular expression strings into a new regular expression string. (You have to remember that you're talking to a computer, and computers are **very** stupid!)

To do the pig latin game you'll probably want to just gather a substring of non-vowels and then check whether it's 0-length (starts with a vowel) or not.